# PHP curl echo not displaying in browser

Tags: php, curl, post, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to display the response string from a PHP POST request in the browser. If I run:

```
<?php
$project_id = "abcdefgh";
$session_id = "123456789";
$url = "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/".$project_id."/agent/sessions/".$session_id.":detectIntent";

$query = '{
            "query_input": {
            "text": {
                "text": "Test input",
                "language_code": "en-US"
            }
            }
        }';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

in VSCode, I get the following response (this is expected behavior):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

However, if I navigate to the index.php file running on my WAMP server in Chrome, I get a blank screen. I can echo other strings, such as:

[image: Example echo]

I can even copy the response directly, and echo the response as a string in the browser. It just seems to not work with the post request (maybe it is a timing thing?). This could be a WAMP configuration/permissions problem, but I feel the problem might be elsewhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Do you want to recover an error message?

Comment: Executing your code locally, gives me the exact result you say you expected. _“I get a blank screen.”_ - do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go do that first of all.

Comment: you have to authenticate and tell curl to send it as JSON `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Bearer add_token_here_'));
`

Comment: use var_dump($result) or use print_r($result);

Comment: The php_error log does not display anything. If I var_dump the $result, I get "C:\wamp64\www\chat\index.php:30:boolean false" in the browser, but "string(304)" followed by the string of the response in the terminal. Why is there any difference between the terminal and the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download and add cacert.pem to my php.ini file and restart my WAMP server to get it to work. It was an error with the curl call.

Answer (score 0):

Because your return is an object, you must access it by following its object chain. Unable to execute `echo` an object, you must retrieve the message attribute and return a string.

```
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Decode object ()
$result = json_decode($result);

// Message error
echo $result->error->message;

curl_close($ch);
```

---

Reference: [Object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/hwapi.object.php)

Comment: A var_dump gives me string(304). I get the following error when I run your code:https://imgur.com/1EBSMOj

Comment: Your getting that since curl response don't have key "error" or "message". I guess there should be some error in curl call.